# Light-weight SQL ETL tool compatible with Redshift

Tags: sql, redshift

I'm looking for a light-weight SQL ETL tool compatible with Amazon Redshift.

The primary (currently the only) use case would be to schedule queries that perform aggregations on Redshift tables, and load the results back into other Redshift tables (either by creating a new table, or executing an `INSERT INTO` on an existing table).

A concrete example might be "perform SQL query Q on table T1 daily, and insert the resulting rows into table T2 with a date column appended".

This type of thing could be accomplished by setting up cron jobs for each desired query. However, I want the tool to be usable by non-engineering (but SQL proficient) users. Therefore, I'm looking for something with a nice UI, and possibly a drag-and-drop interface for defining transformations.

To be clear, I don't need to connect data from different sources (ex. load data from a SQL database into Redshift; this type of thing seems to be what a lot of tools focus on), but a tool that did this type of thing and also had good support for my use case would work.

What I've tried so far:

1. [Matillion](http://www.matillion.com/etl-redshift/) - Functionality-wise, this is the closest thing I've found to what I want. I like the easy setup via AWS marketplace. However, the UI is not as polished as I would like. For example, I couldn't figure out how to disconnect components without deleting one of them, and the job scheduling page didn't show up correctly on my browser.
2. [Xplenty](https://www.xplenty.com/) - I really like the UI, but it can't do aggregation at the data source level (only filtering). It tries to load input data into its own cluster, and do the aggregation there, which is not what I want (since Redshift is already really good at this).

Comment: I can't give you an unbiased recommendation, since I work for Matillion! But could I ask you to get in touch with our [support team](http://redshiftsupport.matillion.com), as I'd like to find out why the scheduling isn't displaying properly. Deleting a link should be an option if you right-click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at a Talend.

> By using Talend’s connectors to Amazon Redshift, users will be able to load and extract data to and from Amazon Redshift...

I am biased given I work for Talend.

https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/partners-detail/talend/